# Escape characters for echo/printf?

Tags: bash, printf, echo

So I'm trying to write this script where it will echo out a name of a command, but I don't want it to actually run that command that it's echoing out, in this example I'm using `screen`

```
printf "You run this command with screen to run in a background."
```

but what I find to be having issue with this is that it's running `screen` command in that printed output, and it shows an error as a result. Is there some escape character I need to enter to prevent this from happening, so that the rest of the script can run properly?

Comment: Are you sure you're running what you say you're running?  There's no way the above will execute the screen command.

Comment: I am sure, I just said so before that it outputs an error when I try to run it in my own script.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

When you write an expression within `double quotes in bash` it will execute the commands within it. If you don't want it to execute the command enclose your statement within `single quotes`

```
 'You run this command with screen to run in a background.'
```

Comment: so there's actual differences between Double and Single quotes huh?

Comment: Yes, anything within single quotes won't be recognized as a command

Comment: Just enclosing an expression in double quotes won't result in it getting executed!  Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Comment: This is **wrong answer**. No command is executed within double quotes, unless you explicitly don't ask for it. Try: `echo "date"` or `printf "date"` will output the string `date` and not the current date. Even without the quotes, e.g. `printf date` will not execute the command. You must use `echo "$(date)"` for executing. How this could get accepted?!